# Unable to install a package on pi zero

Tags: raspbian-stretch, packages

**Colleagues,
I am trying to install a package using**

pi@pizero:~ $ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed

```
   Depends: git-man (> 1:2.11.0) but it is not going to be installed

   Depends: git-man (< 1:2.11.0-.) but it is not going to be installed
```

libraspberrypi-bin : Depends: libraspberrypi0 (= 1.20190819~stretch-1) but 1.20190401-1 is to be installed

libraspberrypi-dev : Depends: libraspberrypi0 (= 1.20190819~stretch-1) but 1.20190401-1 is to be installed

libraspberrypi-doc : Depends: libraspberrypi0 (= 1.20190819~stretch-1) but 1.20190401-1 is to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

**Tried as suggested the comment**

pi@pizero:~ $ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Correcting dependencies... Done

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

libsasl2-modules
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.

The following additional packages will be installed:

libraspberrypi0 raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel

The following packages will be upgraded:

libraspberrypi0 raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel

3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

4 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/39.8 MB of archives.

After this operation, 7,770 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Reading changelogs... Done

(Reading database ... 35721 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../raspberrypi-kernel_1.20190819~stretch-1_armhf.deb ...

Adding 'diversion of /boot/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb to /usr/share/rpikernelhack/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb by rpikernelhack'

Progress: [  4%] [#####........................................................................................................................]

**And finally gets stucked here . After few minutes putty alerts me "lost connection" . So I reboot and comes back fine, but if I tried the same commands, same result.**

Information from my system :

pi@pizero:~ $ cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"

VERSION_ID="9"

VERSION="9 (stretch)"

VERSION_CODENAME=stretch

ID=raspbian

ID_LIKE=debian

HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"

SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"

BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

pi@pizero:~ $
pi@pizero:~ $

**Sources Lists**

pi@pizero:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

-#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'

#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

pi@pizero:~ $ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
mosquitto-stretch.list  raspi.list
pi@pizero:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mosquitto-stretch.list
deb https://repo.mosquitto.org/debian stretch main
pi@pizero:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
-# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
pi@pizero:~ $

pi@pizero:~ $ df -Bm

Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on

/dev/root         14535M 1317M    12599M  10% /

devtmpfs            213M    0M      213M   0% /dev

tmpfs               217M    0M      217M   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs               217M    4M      214M   2% /run

tmpfs                 5M    1M        5M   1% /run/lock

tmpfs               217M    0M      217M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/mmcblk0p1       43M   22M       21M  51% /boot

tmpfs                44M    0M       44M   0% /run/user/1000

pi@pizero:~ $

**Any idea on to fix this?
cheers,
martin**

Comment: Try upgrading to RaspiOS 32 Buster. Stretch is end-of-support.

Comment: Thank you. I have already re installed